# Testing variable for pattern

Tags: regex, bash

I need to ensure a variable passed to my shell script matches a certain pattern.
var x has to be in the form of AA-X.X.XX (ie AA-1.2.33). If it doesn't match I need to exit.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Bash has direct support for regular expressions.

```
if ! [[ $mystring ~= $pattern ]]; then
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Bash's Double-Bracket Regex Tests

See [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the GNU Bash Manual for a complete explanation of the `=~` binary operator. As an example:

```
good_string='AA-1.2.33'
bad_string='BB.11.222.333'
regex='^AA-[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$'

[[ "$good_string" =~ $regex ]]
echo $? # 0

[[ "$bad_string" =~ $regex ]]
echo $? # 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!
I think I was being too strict. I ended up using the following as the digit mask can change over time.

Answer (score 0):

Doable directly in bash

```
var=AA-1.2.33
[[ $var =~ ^AA-.\..\...$ ]]
echo $?
0
var=AA-1.2.3355
[[ $var =~ ^AA-.\..\...$ ]]
echo $?
1
```

Comment: `if  [[ $myString == AA-* ]]
    then
echo $? # 0
echo "hurray!"
else
echo $? # 0
echo "nope"
fi`